# GridView doesn't show Linq to Object Result

Tags: c#, linq

i sent XElement to my method to convert it to objects

and it result assigned to DataGrid source( method return 832 object )

but gridview doesn't show any thing

```
dgv.DataSource = from objselect in Utility.ListXElementToDeclaration(query)
                        select objselect;
```

Comment: Do you call `DataBind()` after setting the data source?

Comment: add code dgv.DataBind();

Comment: dgv.DataBind() don't appear in intellisense !

Comment: If this is WinForms instead of WebForms, there isn't a DataBind method.

Comment: it appears dgv in this context stands for DataGridView - Did you assign it in the form_load event? Where are you using the above shown code in your form events? Are you using BindingSource anyway..?

Comment: Check this example - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `objselect` should have some properties (not fields)
2. `dgv.AutoGenerateColumns` should be `true`, or you should have some columns defined
3. You probably need a `List<>` : `dgv.DataSource = (from .. select objselect).ToList();`

And it's not a bad idea to use a BindingSource as a middleman between dgv and the List.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe force the query to execute, by changing it to

```
dgv.DataSource = (from objselect in Utility.ListXElementToDeclaration(query)
                  select objselect).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DataTable dt =  from objselect in Utility.ListXElementToDeclaration(query)
                        select objselect;

dgv.DataSource = dt;
dgv.DataBind();
```

Comment: cant assign objselect to datatable,

Comment: @HamidrezaShahmoradi Hm.. have u a class to set the result? or any other variable?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try seeing if you have results in the object that is returned by doing something like this.

```
var x = from objselect in Utility.ListXElementToDeclaration(query) 
                    select objselect;
```

Then examine x to see what is inside.  Maybe nothing is being returned or something is wrong with the linq statement.  I sometimes convert my results of a linq query to a List also like this.

```
var x = (from objselect in Utility.ListXElementToDeclaration(query) 
                    select objselect).ToList();
```

Comment: i see returned list, it contain 830 object in correct format,